# Asset type is always credit_alphanum12?

Tags: assets, issuing

I tried creating an asset by following this link: [Issuing Assets](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html).

I am able to successfully issue asset and transfer to another account. But when I check the balance of other accounts, I get:

```
Type: credit_alphanum12 , Balance: 10.0000000
Type: credit_alphanum12 , Balance: 10.0000000
Type: native , Balance: 9981.9998400
```

I don't know why the assets name didn't appear. I can't distinguish between assest if I don't see their names.

This is the code snippet I used:

**To issuse asset**

```
// Create an object to represent the new asset
//var astroDollar = new StellarSdk.Asset('AstroDollar', issuingKeys.publicKey());
```

**Complete code:**

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('http://127.0.0.1:8000', {allowHttp: true});

// Keys for accounts to issue and receive the new asset
var issuingKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
  .fromSecret('______secret key_issuer__________');
var receivingKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
  .fromSecret('______secret key_receiver__________');

// Create an object to represent the new asset
//var astroDollar = new StellarSdk.Asset('AstroDollar', issuingKeys.publicKey());
var astroDollar = new StellarSdk.Asset('AstroDollar', issuingKeys.publicKey());

// First, the receiving account must trust the asset
server.loadAccount(receivingKeys.publicKey())
  .then(function(receiver) {
    var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(receiver)
      // The `changeTrust` operation creates (or alters) a trustline
      // The `limit` parameter below is optional
      .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.changeTrust({
        asset: astroDollar,
        limit: '1000'
      }))
      .build();
    transaction.sign(receivingKeys);
    return server.submitTransaction(transaction);
  })

  // Second, the issuing account actually sends a payment using the asset
  .then(function() {
    return server.loadAccount(issuingKeys.publicKey())
  })
  .then(function(issuer) {
    var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(issuer)
      .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: receivingKeys.publicKey(),
        asset: astroDollar,
        amount: '10'
      }))
      .build();
    transaction.sign(issuingKeys);
    console.log("success")
    return server.submitTransaction(transaction);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Error!', error);
  });
```

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you are parsing `/accounts/{id}` endpoint. A single balance object is of the following form:

```
{
  "balance": "0.0000000",
  "limit": "922337203685.4775807",
  "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
  "asset_code": "BTC",
  "asset_issuer": "GATEMHCCKCY67ZUCKTROYN24ZYT5GK4EQZ65JJLDHKHRUZI3EUEKMTCH"
}
```

You are probably printing `asset_type` field only. You should print `asset_code` and `asset_issuer` fields because they uniquely represent an asset.

Comment: OMG. Never paid attention to this. Thanks.